# When I use css3 transform scale() and rotate(), there are some weird unknown border line

Tags: css, sass, rotation, transform, scale

When I use css3 transform scale() and rotate(), there are some weird unknown border line.

Before add ***transform:scale()*** :
[image]

After add ***transform:scale()*** :
[image]

I don't know what's problem here...

This is my html:

```
<div class="logo">
  <div class="logo-modifing"></div>
</div>
```

and scss:

```
  .logo {
    width: 25px;
    height: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: -9px;
    overflow: hidden;
    scale: (1.5);   <---------------After add this scale()


    &:before {
      content: '';
      width: 30px;
      height: 20px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 2px;
      right: 0;
      background-color: black;
      border-top-right-radius: 45% 60%;
      transform: rotate(-20deg);
    }

    &:after {
      content: '';
      width: 30px;
      height: 20px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      right: -4px;
      background-color: white;
      border-top-right-radius: 60% 25%;
      transform: rotate(-20deg);
    }

    .logo-modifing {
      width: 20px;
      height: 30px;
      position: absolute;
      top: -5px;
      right: 19px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: white;
      transform: rotate(-20deg);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Given scale = 1.5, `.logo` width is 25 * 1.5 = 37.5 and height is 15 * 1.5 = 22.5. Try making width and height _after_ scaling integer.